# How to replace "scopeLineCSS" from "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" with native vsc configuration?

Tags: visual-studio-code

With "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2", we can give a custom line between a bracket pair, one configuration is like following:

```
    "bracket-pair-colorizer-2.scopeLineCSS": [
    "borderStyle : dashed",
    "borderWidth : 3px",
    "borderColor : {color}",
    "opacity: 0.5"
],
```

How can we do this with the native vsc configuration?

For example, we can add `"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": true` into `settings.json` to give colors for the bracket pairs. I didn't find the configuration for the `scopeLineCSS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is in the question itself.)

```
"bracket-pair-colorizer-2.scopeLineCSS": [
    "borderStyle : dashed",
    "borderWidth : 3px",
    "borderColor : {color}",
    "opacity: 0.5"
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but this configuration only works when "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" is enabled, this is not a VSC native config. 

As you may know, "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" is not maintained any more, and I'm looking for a way to get the same result with "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" disabled.

Comment: I know that "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" is not maintained any more. I was looking for a solution myself and found only this unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for the share, seems I will have to keep "Bracket Pair Colorizer 2" enabled for some days.